# Best practice when slightly modifying inherited init method?

Tags: python, inheritance, scikit-learn

I wanted to make a class very similar to an existing one in python's sklearn library, allowing one to specify one additional argument when creating it. Normally, I would do something like the following:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion

class Foo(FeatureUnion):
    def __init__(self, *args, some_bool=False, **kwargs):
        self.some_bool = some_bool
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #

foo = Foo(transformer_list=[("transformer 1", None), ("transformer 2", None)])
```

This gives a runtime error:

> scikit-learn estimators should always specify their parameters in the
>   signature of their **init** (no varargs).  with
>   constructor (self, *args, some_bool=False, **kwargs) doesn't  follow
>   this convention.

What is the best practice for accomplishing something like this? Is this issue specific to sklearn, or should one generally avoid this sort of thing (and in that case, what should be done instead?).

Comment: As an option, make a class, that holds your variable parameters inside. And provide your init method with an instance of this class.